# neo4j escaping for regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, neo4j, escaping

I receive a user input `keyword` and want to use it to search my database. I built a query that looks something like this:

`db.execute("MATCH (n:User) WHERE n.firstname CONTAINS {keyword} OR n.lastname CONTAINS {keyword} RETURN n.username", params);`

But this isn't case sensitive, so I thought of manually building the expression and using regular expressions, sort of as follows:

`db.execute("MATCH (n:User) WHERE n.firstname =~ '(?i).*" + keyword + ".*' OR n.lastname =~ '(?i).*" + keyword + ".*' RETURN n.username");`

I'm looking either for a function for escaping the regex or a better solution for making the query case-insensitive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest storing the properties as all lowercase (or uppercase) and then using the Cypher `lower()` function to convert user input to lowercase for comparison.

**Add lowercase name properties**

```
MATCH (n:User)
SET n.lowerFirstName = lower(n.firstname),
    n.lowerLastName = lower(n.lastname)
```

**Find lower case matches based on user input**

```
db.execute("MATCH (n:User) WHERE n.lowerFirstName CONTAINS lower({keyword}) OR n.lowerLastName CONTAINS lower({keyword}) RETURN n.username", params);
```

Comment: The does solve the problem, but I prefer adding `lower()` to both sides of the CONTAINS operand rather than maintaining consistency for another pair of variables. Thanks for simple the solution!